# Is English the only language that always capitalizes "I"?

Tags: etymology, capitalization, personal-pronouns

Is English the only language where "I" is always capitalized, no matter where it occurs in a sentence? The other two languages that I'm familiar with don't do this.

In German, "ich" is only capitalized at the start of a sentence; the same is true for "yo" in Spanish.

If English is unique in this regard, or even if among a subset of languages that do this, is there a historical reason behind it? A philosopical or cultural one, or...???

Comment: But in English, we also capitalize nationalities and languages.

Comment: @TimWard: Good point; but thinking of it from a philosophical/cultural perspective, drawing attention to something (such as a person's nationality) by capitalizing it is not always complimentary - that is, it may not be meant that way.

Comment: I have two suspicions which cannot be verified due to the nature of human existence and our documented history. First, the capital I just looks better on the written page and is easier to see from a visual pattern perspective. Second, I expect the writs from Her or His Majesty may have influenced the practices and patterns of all English speakers, and I'm sure the Royalty would never reduce their personal pronouns to lowercase. ;)

Comment: In general, a handwritten lower-case "i" would be apt to get lost in the clutter.  And, back before printing presses, the capitalization of words (and their spelling) was quite arbitrary and capricious.

Comment: (It would be instructive to try to find another language that has a personal pronoun or similar critical word that is a single letter represented as a single stroke, or something approximating that.  The closest you come in English is the article "a", but the "indefinite article" is just about the most disposable word in the language, so there's little need to be concerned with preserving it when the handwriting gets murky.)

Comment: @TimWard: but influence from royal spelling would tend to apply to capitalized "We," I'd assume.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has suggested migrating this to Linguistics SE.  Most of the question is about all the other languages in the world that are written.

Comment: @sumelic, with 'we' it isn't as necessary due to pattern recognition. Per my previous comment, I do believe that was the primary factor in this development. Somehow, I can just hear a Python-esque conversation about this...

Comment: I'm curious why there are two down-votes on this question..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about English, it is a question about all other languages.

Comment: @Chenmunka: No, it's a question about English *and* other languages, but focuses on English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English is at the least very lonely in this stance. We may very well be the only language that does capitalize the first person singular pronoun. Here's some reading to keep you busy.

[Why Do We Capitalize I?](http://blog.dictionary.com/whycapitali/)

[Only English Speakers Capitalize 'I,' But That Doesn't Mean We're Obsessed With Ourselves](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/06/09/english-first-person-pronouns_n_7485402.html)

[Me, Myself and I](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/08/03/magazine/03wwln-guestsafire-t.html)

[Why Do We Capitalize “I”?](http://mentalfloss.com/article/30743/why-do-we-capitalize-%E2%80%9Ci%E2%80%9D)

Answer (score 7):

I think the reason is very simple. If you write "i" it is so small a letter that often it can happen you fail to see it, especially in fast handwriting when the dot is often neglected. " I" has nothing to do with philosophy or culture or an overestimated ego.

To my knowledge, and I have looked into about 25 to 30 languages just to understand their system and mainly to better see how I learn a foreign language English is the  only language that uses "I" instead of "i" just for better readability.

Comment: Latin doesn't have subject pronouns (*Veni, vidi, vici*), so we can't blame the Romans.

Comment: @WS2: *Ego, tu, nos, vos,*

Comment: @WS2 it *has* them, it just doesn't *use* them as much as English does.  In this respect it is similar to Spanish (unsurprisingly).

Comment: @phoog But are they used as subjects? It is more than half a century since I studied Latin!

Comment: @WS2 yes. They're subject pronouns after all.  They are used for emphasis or contrast, for example.  Ego te video et tu me vidis.

Answer (score 1):

This is not so much a question about English, but more about every language other than English.

German, for example, capitalizes [*Sie*, when it is used as a formal "you"](http://germanforenglishspeakers.com/basics/capitalization-and-punctuation/). Traditionally, *Du* is also capitalized, especially in correspondence.  Is that the "same" as in English?  Is there a rationale for any of these orthographic conventions?  Does this superficial trait tell you anything useful about the languages that happen to share these quirks?  You decide.

Comment: So it's interesting that in German words referencing others are sometimes capitalized ("Sie" und "Du"), but the one used to reference oneself ("ich") only at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: As a German I can say that in a letter to a very dear person "Du"  is an expression of respect, estimation and politeness. "Sie" as address for  one  or several persons is a differention of "sie". My sister (sie), the people (sie). So German has three different "sie".